# Does Service stack allow authentication using Google OpenId connect?

Tags: .net, servicestack, openid-connect

I would like to add Google authentication on my service stack web application but it looks like it does not support OpenID connect. It only supports Open Id 2.0 which is the older version.
https://docs.servicestack.net/openid

If I would like to add Google authentication to service stack web app, Do I have to use older version of Open Id or anyone has better suggestion?

If anybody has google authentication on their service stack website, please let me know how are they are doing it and are there any challenges?

AppHost.cs

```
//Load Plugins
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() =>
                new CustomAuthSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { customProvider,
                new GoogleAuthProvider(AppSettings)}));
```

Do I have to install a package to get Google Auth to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of ServiceStack's .NET Core Templates are already pre-configured with Google Auth support, see:

- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/razor
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/script
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcauth
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentityserver
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-spa
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vuetify-spa
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-nuxt
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-lite
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/react-spa
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/react-lite
- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-spa

Comment: But my project is not in .Net Core. It target .Net Framework 4.6.1 
It is an existing project. I also tried adding Google Oauth2 and OpenId Nuget package but I started getting errors regarding references to Service stacks

Comment: @LearnAspNet The same `GoogleAuthProvider` implementation used in .NET Core projects in the primary ServiceStack NuGet package is also available to .NET Framework and many of the same project templates listed here have [.NET Framework Project equivalents](https://github.com/NetFrameworkTemplates) with the `-netfx` suffix.

Comment: I updated my question with LoadPlugins method. Do I have to install any Nuget Package to get that GoogleAuthProvider. I am curernly on Service Stack 4.5.8
@mythz

Comment: @LearnAspNet It was [added in 2018 in the v5.4 Release](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.4#google-auth-provider) that's in the main ServiceStack NuGet package.

Comment: thank you! so, just to confirm I will have to update my service stack to 5.4 to use Google Authentication, right? @mythz
Or there is any other way around it?

Comment: @LearnAspNet At least v5.4 but updating to the most recent version is always preferred

Comment: Can we customize the scope in GoogleAuthProvider to get more details like their phone number, address or calendar? Also can we view the details of the 
Identity and access token and parse and save those results in our database?

Comment: @LearnAspNet please open a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61066809/can-we-add-authorization-scopes-for-external-logins-and-save-results-to-database