# Can we add authorization scopes for external logins and save results to database in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

Can we customize the scope in GoogleAuthProvider to get more details like their phone number, address or calendar, profile picture?

Also can we view the details of the Identity and access token and parse and save those results in our database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register additional Scopes in the `GoogleAuthProvider.Scopes` collection which [by default is populated with](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/GoogleAuthProvider.cs#L41-L44):

```
this.Scopes = new[] {
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
};
```

The OAuth Info from all [ServiceStack's OAuth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#oauth-providers) are [populated in the registered Auth Repository](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#user-auth-repository) in the [UserAuthDetails](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0d60f0c4d4286fdd32c7de576f12dd907ff68286/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L58) table where the Access Token is stored in `AccessTokenSecret`.

You can retrieve additional info about the user using the Access Token and overriding `CreateAuthInfo` in a custom `GoogleAuthProvider` and overriding the `CreateAuthInfo()` implementation which by default retrieves basic info about the user from the `UserProfileUrl` (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo):

```
protected override Dictionary<string, string> CreateAuthInfo(string accessToken)
{
    var url = this.UserProfileUrl.AddQueryParam("access_token", accessToken);
    var json = url.GetJsonFromUrl();
    var obj = JsonObject.Parse(json);

    obj.MoveKey("id", "user_id");
    obj.MoveKey("given_name", "first_name");
    obj.MoveKey("family_name", "last_name");
    obj.MoveKey("picture", AuthMetadataProvider.ProfileUrlKey, profileUrl => profileUrl.SanitizeOAuthUrl());

    return obj;
}
```

The returned dictionary populates all well-known properties on `UserAuthDetails` in the overridable [LoadUserAuthInfo()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/e426ea685f930ec32216f48f5502c3ea90d067ea/src/ServiceStack/Auth/OAuth2Provider.cs#L150) (which can alternatively be intercepted with the `LoadUserAuthFilter` on each AuthProvider). All other non-matching properties in the dictionary are saved in the `Items` Dictionary on the `UserAuthDetails` table.